# How to pass a variable from bash to regex

Tags: regex, bash, sed, sh

I'm trying to print only lines that contain the variable $foo. I've tried using double quotes and curly braces to no avail. What is the proper way to pass a shell variable to a regex in sed?

```
sed -n 's:\("${foo}".*$\):\1:p' file.txt
```

Comment: Are you sure your problem is passing the variable? Have you verified that you have a match when you use the literal value?

Comment: The single quotes prevent the variable substitution. You need to do something like this: `sed -n 's:\('"${foo}"'.*$\):\1:p' file.txt`. Use echo on that line to see (more or less) what is going on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sed` is overkill if you don't actually need to modify the matching lines. Just use `grep`:

```
grep "$foo" file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below sed command to print the lines which contains  value assigned to the variable `foo`.

```
sed -n "/$foo/p" file
```

Comment: +1 for correct sed command, -1 for using the wrong tool. You see, nobody said that ``$foo`` variable does not contain any special characters. And you know what happens if something like a ``/`` gets inside ``$foo``. There is no such problem with grep solution.

Comment: @Aleks-DanielJakimenko good point. BUt op wants a sed solution. So i posted it. And also if the variable contains special characters then why he choose sed for printing the corresponding lines.

Comment: That's why I didn't downvote :) But sometimes people ask for wrong things, and giving them an answer just makes it worse.

Answer (score 0):

Using single quote you get the result like

```
$-pattern='foo'
$-sed 's/('$pattern'.*$)/<\1>/g'
  fo
  fo
  foo
  <foo>
```